# Nested loops - access property: the key item should point to a dictionary

Tags: ansible

What am I doing wrong?

```yaml
admins:
  - name: "{{ vault_admin_user1_name }}"
    sshkey:
      - "{{ vault_admin_user1_pubkeyA }}"
      - "{{ vault_admin_user1_pubkeyC }}"

- name: Set up multiple authorized keys for users
  ansible.posix.authorized_key:
    user: '{{ item.name }}'
    state: present
    key: '{{ item.sshkey }}'
  loop: "{{ admins|subelements('sshkey.item') }}"
```

When I try to iterate over admin's properties I got:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ admins|subelements('sshkey.item') }}): the key item should point to a dictionary, got '[1st key,2nd key...]}

Comment: Your question is unclear. What should the final `loop` look like? What is inside your `admins` dictionary or list?

Comment: @hc_dev - I'm trying to loop both over users in admins list and for each user i want to add multiple ssh keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to:

> loop over users [`name`] in admins list
>
> and for each user add multiple ssh keys [`sshkey`]

(I added property names in brackets)

You could use 3 ways:

#### Use `with_subelements`

```yaml
- ansible.posix.authorized_key:
    user: '{{ item.0.name }}'
    state: present
    key: '{{ item.1 }}'
  with_subelements:
    - "{{admins}}"
    - sshkey
```

where `{{admins}}` is your outer-loop, becomes `item.0` (outer element)
and `sshkey` is your inner-loop, becomes `item.1` (inner element).

See the example in
[Ansible with_subelements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908715/ansible-with-subelements)
and compare the Ansible docs [`with_subelements`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements).

#### Use `loop` with `subelements`

```yaml
- ansible.posix.authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.0.name }}"
    state: "{{ item.0.state | default('present') }}"
    key: "{{ item.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ admins | subelements('sshkey', 'skip_missing=True') }}"
```

Now the `admins` before pipe-symbol (filter) is the outer-element, whereas `sshkey` is the inner-element .

See the article explaining it well for a similar case:

- Build A Homelab(2018): [Using subelements in Ansible to loop through multiple lists](https://www.buildahomelab.com/2018/11/03/subelements-ansible-loop-nested-lists/)

#### Jinja for-loop

Alternatively you could use Jinja2's loops like explained in
[Iterating through Python dictionary with Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50825155/iterating-through-python-dictionary-with-jinja2).